# Primefaces data table Row selection and multiple checkbox selection not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using `primeface 3.5` where i find the check box to select and unselect or row select  work perfectly independently . While I tried to have both  the row selection and check box selection ,row selection event is not triggering . Could any one clarify this for me ?

row select is not working thou check all event is working

```
<p:dataTable id="myBookDTable" var="car" value="#{myBean.pageViews}" paginatorPosition="bottom" paginator="true" rows="30" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="400" scrollRows="30" paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" rowsPerPageTemplate="30,50,100"rowKey="#{car.carID}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" draggableColumns="true" lazy="true">

<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{myBean.onRowSelect}" update="certainpart"
                                async="true"/>
<p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="#{myBean.rowSelectCheckbox}"/>
<p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" listener="#{myBean.rowUnselectCheckbox}"/>

<p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{myBean.rowUnselect}"/>

<p:column  width="30" selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%" />

</p:datatable>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Please post your code and exact problem you are facing

Comment: are you sure the problem only occurs when you are using them both?

Comment: @LiranElisha : YES ,i am facing the problem only while using both

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For column header event we have a different header name exist in primeface/jsf:
"toggleSelect".
You can use like this:

```
<p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update="@this" process="@this" />
```

Comment: <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update="@this" process="@this" />

Comment: This is good, but how can I find out if I just made "selectAll" or "unselectAll"?

Answer (score 22):

In your `datatable` tag, 
Use this

```
   <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" update="someComponent" />
  <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" update="someComponent" />
  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="someComponent" />
  <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="someCompoent" />
  <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:4%" />
```

you need to fire these four ajax events and make sure you make the column `selectionMode` as `multiple`

Comment: That works when you select individual rows - not when you select the column header checkbox!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update=":form:component" partialSubmit="true" />
```

The source:

PrimeFaces 4.0 User Guide.- Ajax Behavior Events